# How to use Azure Key Vault Python SDK to add access policy?

Tags: python, azure-keyvault, pulumi

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically add new access policies to an Azure Key Vault resource.

My base stack is Pulumi (azure-native) which doesn't provide the functionality to do that; it only allows to add access policies when creating the Key Vault resource.

Apparently, there are some Python SDKs for working with Azure Key Vault, but I couldn't find a way to use them for managing access policies.

Does any of the Azure Key Vault Python SDKs provide a way to add access policies to Key Vault? If not, what are my choices (alternative solutions) here?

Comment: Tracked in https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues/594

Answer (score 0):

Manages a Key Vault Access Policy.

```css
import pulumi
import pulumi_azure as azure

current = azure.core.get_client_config()
example_resource_group = azure.core.ResourceGroup("exampleResourceGroup", location="West Europe")
example_key_vault = azure.keyvault.KeyVault("exampleKeyVault",
    location=example_resource_group.location,
    resource_group_name=example_resource_group.name,
    tenant_id=current.tenant_id,
    sku_name="premium")
example_access_policy = azure.keyvault.AccessPolicy("exampleAccessPolicy",
    key_vault_id=example_key_vault.id,
    tenant_id=current.tenant_id,
    object_id=current.object_id,
    key_permissions=["Get"],
    secret_permissions=["Get"])
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using pulumi azure-native, not azure-classic. Doesn't using both at the same time make issues/conflicts?